# How can I create table from any vertica query

Tags: vertica

CREATE TABLE demo_test AS
(
Drop table if exists a; create local temp table b on commit preserve row as (SELECT * FROM ddd); Drop table if exists x; create local temp table c on commit preserve row as (SELECT * FROM ddd1); Drop table if exists y; create local temp table zz on commit preserve row as (SELECT * FROM ddd2);
);

SELECT * FROM demo_test

Comment: You cannot nest SQL statements as you seem to be trying here. What do you want to drop? What do you want to create? there is table a, x and y to drop; there is table b and c and zz to be created. Do you want `demo_test` to contain any data at the end? And what would that be?

Answer (score 0):

If `demo_test` has the same structure as `ddd`, `ddd1` and `ddd2`, and you want the result of all selects you specified to land in `demo_test`, then it would be:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo_test;                                                                                                                                                                                

CREATE TABLE demo_test 
AS
SELECT * FROM ddd
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ddd1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ddd2
;
```